# How to switch Baseurl on retry and retry in Kotlin Flow with Retrofit exceptions

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-flow

I am using Kotlin flow to consume the Rest APIs. I have three baseurl ex  api.xyz.com, api2.xyz.com and api3.xyz.com. If first baseurl gives retrofit exception, I want to switch to another base URL.

Hint like in Rxjava we can switch the baseurl, how can we do using kotlin flow?

I'm using extensions function i.e.

```
fun <T : Any> Flow<Resource<T>>.execute(
    @ServiceExecutor.ServiceType serviceType: Int,
    reconfigure: Boolean
) =
    retryWhen { cause, attempt ->
        Timber.e("retryWhen")
        false
        //handleRetry(cause, attempt)
    }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .catch {
            Timber.e("catch")
            handleExceptions(it, serviceType, reconfigure)
        }
```

On retry I want to switch my baseurl and try to execute same function once more.